# Photon distribution from a classical radiative event

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I became curious about the number and frequency distribution of photons emitted from a simple radiative event:

Small charged object given a mechanical hit.  Non-relativistic, not a delta function, Mechanical hit modeled on a well defined smooth pulse.  Radiative reaction forces negligible.

So, Larmour's formula gives the instantaneous power, integrating with the pulse gives the total energy.  The Lienard-Wiechert potentials will give the classical fields and a Fourier transform will give the (continuous) classical spectrum. The photon picture will be a finite discrete spectrum whose h-bar-omegas and number counts should add up to the calculated energy and I'm supposing the discrete frequency spectrum to resemble the classical continuous one.

What direction should I go next or am I approaching this in a completely wrong way?

Comment: It's likely the Lienard-Wiechert potentials are going to be overkill since you are staying it's a non-relativistic event where velocities are small compared to c.

Comment: Why would a photon picture be finite discrete spectrum? To get the quantum state of the electromagnetic field you will still need to solve Maxwell equations (albeit in a different form), so I would expect to see spectrum very similar to the classical one. Maybe a good idea would be to understand forced quantum harmonic oscillators. This would allow you to actually compute the state of the electromagnetic field you would create by wiggling an electron. Spoiler alert - you will probably get a coherent state (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state)